# No Wi-Fi Adapter found -- Ubuntu 19.10 Intel AC 9560 Windows Dual Boot

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, 19.10, iwlwifi

I am attempting to set up my Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 7 laptop to dual boot with Ubuntu 19.10.  I have not been able to hook up the wireless internet despite several hours of searching and trying solutions from this site and others.

Here's what I've tried so far, the commands are not in order because after so many hours my brain is fried and I can't really remember everything I did.

- Ubuntu 19.10 dual boot with Windows 10 Pro
- Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 7
- Intel AC-9560

Fast-boot and Secure boot disabled

**uname -r**

```
5.3.0-40-generic

ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:75:a4:34:f0:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s20f0u4c4i2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:7b:c5:03:e6:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**iwconfig**

```
enp0s20f0u4c4i2  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list**

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0030]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**dmesg | grep iwlwifi**

```
[    2.598246] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    2.598585] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.709154] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x354
[    3.729338] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    3.729448] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.729451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 914595581
[    3.729453] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0
[    3.729454] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3FBC3DBE | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    3.729455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD15D1B75 | trm_hw_status0
[    3.729456] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD4961B0C | trm_hw_status1
[    3.729457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x54FF50B9 | branchlink2
[    3.729458] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x77B3D17B | interruptlink1
[    3.729459] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD5245D37 | interruptlink2
[    3.729460] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8C317F5A | data1
[    3.729461] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF7834B54 | data2
[    3.729462] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF2195280 | data3
[    3.729463] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xED0B0074 | beacon time
[    3.729464] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x442E532E | tsf low
[    3.729465] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5E38FCA7 | tsf hi
[    3.729466] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAFD8AA2A | time gp1
[    3.729467] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x33F180AB | time gp2
[    3.729468] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC34AE93B | uCode revision type
[    3.729469] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAED2D83E | uCode version major
[    3.729469] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9D4B1BD3 | uCode version minor
[    3.729470] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x021E9D8D | hw version
[    3.729471] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFE563190 | board version
[    3.729472] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2B5489D7 | hcmd
[    3.729473] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF36FCF9C | isr0
[    3.729474] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05D36AD8 | isr1
[    3.729475] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3670F31E | isr2
[    3.729476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAA348080 | isr3
[    3.729477] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x299A10DB | isr4
[    3.729478] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA392CB5F | last cmd Id
[    3.729479] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x58410392 | wait_event
[    3.729480] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x95414821 | l2p_control
[    3.729481] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x749F3BF2 | l2p_duration
[    3.729482] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x98A27BE7 | l2p_mhvalid
[    3.729483] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1C4F5C79 | l2p_addr_match
[    3.729484] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x37390811 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    3.729485] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5DC73DE1 | timestamp
[    3.729486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF3EDE5AE | flow_handler
[    3.729522] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.729523] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    3.729524] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    3.729525] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    3.729526] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008CF5C | umac branchlink2
[    3.729527] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[    3.729528] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    3.729529] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[    3.729530] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | umac data2
[    3.729531] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | umac data3
[    3.729532] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
[    3.729533] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor
[    3.729534] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005CF1 | frame pointer
[    3.729535] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer
[    3.729536] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    3.729537] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    3.729554] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    3.729556] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    3.729559] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80260000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    3.729561] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    3.729564] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    3.729566] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4F78052B | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    3.729569] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    3.729571] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    3.729574] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    3.729576] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.729581] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.729586] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    3.729621] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    3.729649] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c61, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    3.729650] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    3.729653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    3.744566] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110'''
```

**sudo modprobe iwlwifi**    – no output

ensured that I had the correct driver in /lib/firmware by checking here:
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

renamed all of the 9000-series drivers except -34, because that worked for another poster.
example:

```
sudo mv iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.bak

 - sudo apt install linux-oem-osp1
 - sudo apt install linux-firmware
 - sudo service fwupd start
 - sudo fwupdmgr refresh
 - sudo fwupdmgr update
 - sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: "Quick start and Secure boot disabled" Do you mean Fast Boot in Windows? Please see: "About dual-boot with Windows and "fast-boot" enabled" here: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant, apologies. I disabled fast-boot before installing Ubuntu. I’ll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the bleeding-edge version worked.
I ran **update-manager -d** to get version 20.04. I didn't have to tinker with anything after rebooting the computer.